# How to update textview depending on retrieved value from Firebase Database

Tags: android, database, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I have asked this question before but I could not get any answer. I am trying to update a textview depending on the result of two other textviews that I retrieve from my firebase database.

I retrieve income from this code block

```
incomeSumReference.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
            @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
            @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                var sum = 0.0

                for (dataSnapshot in snapshot.children) {
                    val map = dataSnapshot.getValue() as Map<*, *>
                    val sumOfIncomes = map.get("itemValue")
                    val sumo = sumOfIncomes.toString()
                    val sumAsDouble: Double = sumo.toDouble()
                    sum += sumAsDouble
                    val stringSum = sum.toString()
                    incomeSumToFormated = formatNumberString(stringSum)
                    profitTextView.text = "+$" + incomeSumToFormated.toString()

                }


            }
            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {

            }
        })
```

And this is for retrieving spent money code block

```
val spentSumReference = database.getReference("users").child(uid).child("Expenses").child(
            currentYear.toString()
        ).child(currentMonthInString.toString())
        spentSumReference.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
            @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                var sum = 0.0

                for (dataSnapshot in snapshot.children) {
                    var map = dataSnapshot.getValue() as Map<String, Object>
                    val sumOfIncomes = map.get("itemValue")
                    var sumo = sumOfIncomes.toString()
                    var sumAsDouble: Double? = sumo.toDouble()
                    sum += sumAsDouble!!

                    var stringSum = sum.toString()
                    var spentSumToFormated =
                        formatNumberString(stringSum) // this is what I want to get outside

                    spentTextView.text = "-$" + spentSumToFormated.toString()
                }
                countExecutedMethods++
            }

            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {

            }

        })
```

I want to make my balanceTextView to show the difference of income and spent money.
But I can't do it because initially they are set to null.

Before running code

```
fun getBalance(){
  val total = income-spent
  balanceTextView.text = "$total"
}
```

I have to make sure functions getIncome() and getExpense() that retrieve data from firebase are already executed. I have tried many approaches but wasn't lucky. What is the best way to do it?

Comment: Have you tried to use nested listeners?

Comment: Are you suggesting instead of making two functions getExpense() and getIncome() I make one function ex: getCurrentMonthData, and use nested listeners to get needed data and under them try the getBalance() function? @AlexMamo

Comment: Yes, exactly. Give it a try and tell me of it works.

Comment: I did exactly like you said. It seems to be working great for now. I will publish my answer below and you can check it. @AlexMamo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as @AlexMamo suggested I used nested listeners and came up with the code below. It seems to be working. If I get any bugs in the future I will make sure to update my answer.

```
val getMonthDataReference = database.getReference("users").child(uid)
        getMonthDataReference.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener{
            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {

            var total = 0.0
                val incomeMoneyQuery = getMonthDataReference.child("Incomes").child(currentYear.toString()).child(currentMonthInString.toString())
                incomeMoneyQuery.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener{
                    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
                    override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                        var sumOfIncome = 0.0
                            for (dataSnapshot in snapshot.children) {
                                val map = dataSnapshot.getValue() as Map<*, *>
                                val sumOfIncomes = map.get("itemValue")
                                val sumo = sumOfIncomes.toString()
                                val sumAsDouble: Double = sumo.toDouble()
                                sumOfIncome += sumAsDouble
                                val stringSum = sumOfIncome.toString()
                                var incomeSumToFormated = formatNumberString(stringSum)
                                incomeTextView!!.text = "+$" + incomeSumToFormated.toString()
                            }
                        total+=sumOfIncome
                        var totalFormated = formatNumberString(total.toString())
                        balance!!.text ="$$totalFormated"
                    }
                    override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                    }
                })
                val spentMoneyQuery = getMonthDataReference.child("Expenses").child(currentYear.toString()).child(currentMonthInString.toString())
                spentMoneyQuery.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener{

                    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
                    override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                        var sumOfSpent = 0.0
                        for (dataSnapshot in snapshot.children) {
                            var map = dataSnapshot.getValue() as Map<String, Object>
                            val sumOfIncomes = map.get("itemValue")
                            var sumo = sumOfIncomes.toString()
                            var sumAsDouble: Double? = sumo.toDouble()
                            sumOfSpent += sumAsDouble!!

                            var stringSum = sumOfSpent.toString()

                            var spentSumToFormated = formatNumberString(stringSum)
                            spentMoneyText!!.text = "-$" + spentSumToFormated.toString()

                        }
                        total-=sumOfSpent
                        var totalFormated = formatNumberString(total.toString())
                        balance!!.text ="$$totalFormated"

                    }

                    override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {

                    }

                })

            }
            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
            }
        })
al getMonthDataReference = database.getReference("users").child(uid)
        getMonthDataReference.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener{
            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {

            var total = 0.0
                val incomeMoneyQuery = getMonthDataReference.child("Incomes").child(currentYear.toString()).child(currentMonthInString.toString())
                incomeMoneyQuery.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener{
                    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
                    override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                        var sumOfIncome = 0.0
                            for (dataSnapshot in snapshot.children) {
                                val map = dataSnapshot.getValue() as Map<*, *>
                                val sumOfIncomes = map.get("itemValue")
                                val sumo = sumOfIncomes.toString()
                                val sumAsDouble: Double = sumo.toDouble()
                                sumOfIncome += sumAsDouble
                                val stringSum = sumOfIncome.toString()
                                var incomeSumToFormated = formatNumberString(stringSum)
                                incomeTextView!!.text = "+$" + incomeSumToFormated.toString()
                            }
                        total+=sumOfIncome
                        var totalFormated = formatNumberString(total.toString())
                        balance!!.text ="$$totalFormated"
                    }
                    override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                    }
                })
                val spentMoneyQuery = getMonthDataReference.child("Expenses").child(currentYear.toString()).child(currentMonthInString.toString())
                spentMoneyQuery.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener{

                    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
                    override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                        var sumOfSpent = 0.0
                        for (dataSnapshot in snapshot.children) {
                            var map = dataSnapshot.getValue() as Map<String, Object>
                            val sumOfIncomes = map.get("itemValue")
                            var sumo = sumOfIncomes.toString()
                            var sumAsDouble: Double? = sumo.toDouble()
                            sumOfSpent += sumAsDouble!!

                            var stringSum = sumOfSpent.toString()

                            var spentSumToFormated = formatNumberString(stringSum)
                            spentMoneyText!!.text = "-$" + spentSumToFormated.toString()

                        }
                        total-=sumOfSpent
                        var totalFormated = formatNumberString(total.toString())
                        balance!!.text ="$$totalFormated"

                    }

                    override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {

                    }

                })

            }
            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
            }
        })
```